# Automorphism of genus 2 surface with 5 fixed points

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups

Is there a self-homeomorphism of a genus 2 (closed, orientable) surface, which has finite order and exactly 5 fixed points?

Of course, the same question can be asked replacing 2 by $g$ and $5$ by any number $k$. An upper bound for possible values of $k$ is (generalized Lefschetz fixed point theorem) $2g+2$.

For $g=0$, a sphere, only $k=0,2$ are possible.

For $g=1$, the torus, $k=0,1,2,3,4$ are all possible. For example, the map $(x,y) \mapsto (y,-x-y)$ is of order 3 and has exactly 3 fixed points.

Comment: From the Riemann-Hurwitz formula one can exclude the possibility that the quotient is a torus. (For any number of fixed points bigger than 2.) But it does not seem to help if the quotient is a sphere.

Comment: There is no such homeomorphism that is conformal for a genus 2 Riemann surface: otherwise it would commute with the hyperelliptic involution, thus induce a self-map of the Riemann sphere quotient by the hyperelliptic involution.  Since fixed points map to fixed points, and since the Riemann sphere has at most two fixed points, that means the fixed points on the genus 2 curve are either 1, 2, 3 or 4.

Comment: Except of course for the hyperelliptic involution itself which has 6 fixed points.

Comment: @ThiKu: Yes, you are right.  I should have said that.

Comment: @JasonStarr, you can drop the "conformal" restriction, as every finite group of homoemorphisms can be realized by a conformal group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Jason and Dylan seemed to have answered this question in the comments, I decided to work out what the generalized version of this kind of statement is.

Let $\sigma$ be an automorphism of a Riemann surface. Any automorphism that is orientation-reversing with a fixed point has a fixed curve, so let's assume $\sigma$ is orientation-preserving.

By Rieman-Hurwitz, if $\sigma$ has order $k$ and $n$ fixed points than:

$$ 2k -n (k-1) \geq 2 - 2g$$

$$n \leq \frac{ 2k + 2g-2}{k-1}= 2+ \frac{2g}{k-1}$$

Moreover if $k$ has order $2$ then the number of fixed points is congruent to $2g+2$ modulo $4$. So this already rules out many possibilities.

In particular, for $g=2$ this rules out $5$.

There are other congruence conditions. If $k$ is a power of a prime $p$ then all the terms in the Riemann-Hurwitz formula are multiples of $p$ except for the $-n(k-1)$ and $2-2g$ so we get $n \equiv 2-2g $ modulo $p$.

so the list of possibilities becomes something like:

$n \leq 2g+2$ and congruent to it mod $4$ (order $2$)

$n \leq g+2$ and congruent to it mod $3$ (order $3$)

$n \leq 2g/3+2$ and even (order $4$)

$n \leq g/2+2$ and congruent to $2-2g$ modulo $5$ (order $5$)

$n \leq g/5+2$ with no congruence condition (order $6$)

I think you can show that almost all of these are actually achieved, by solving the Riemann-Hurwitz equation, drawing the right orbifold, and using the formula for the orbifold fundamental group.

Answer (score 1):

There is an orbifold quotient of an orientable genus two surface that is a sphere with five cone points of order two. However, covering group here is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ so a single homeomorphism will generate this group.

The existence of the quotient is as follows. First, a bit of notation. Following Thurston, we will use $F(n_1, .. n_m)$ to indicate an orbifold with underlying space $F$ and $m$ cone points, where the order of each cone point is given by $n_j$.

Then the Riemann-Hurwitz formula for orbifold euler characteristic is:

$$\chi(F(n_1, .. n_m)) = \chi(F) - \sum_{j=1}^m(1-\frac{1}{n_j}). $$

Note, using this formula we see the only possible orientable orbifold quotient of a genus two surface with five cone points is $S^2(2,2,2,2,2)$. As noted above this quotient can be realized and in fact this is the only case we need to consider. While $\chi(S^2(2,2,2,2,3)) = -2/3$, any three fold cover of this orbifold will have cone points of order 2. All other cases can be dismissed by considering the minimal manifold covering degree in a similar fashion.

From the analysis of the torus, we know that a a torus covers the ``pillowcase'' the orbifold $S^2(2,2,2,2)$. At points other than the cone points this is a 2-1 covering. Thus, we have the following covering $p: T^2(2,2) \to S^2(2,2,2,2,2)$ (forgive the rough sketches). Cone points of order 2 are indicated by dots and the axis of symmetry is indicated by the dashed line.

[image: $T^2(2,2) covers S^2(2,2,2,2,2)$]
[image: The orientable genus 2 surface covers $T^2(2,2)$]

One can do a case analysis to show that a cyclic covering from the genus 2 surface to $S^2(2,2,2,2,2)$ does not exist. By looking for subgroups of $\pi_1^{orb}(S^2(2,2,2,2,2)$ that are isomorphic to the fundamental group of the genus two surface.

The following MAGMA code shows does this case analysis and shows that all quotient groups are $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

```
> G := Group<a,b,c,d,e|a*b*c*d*e, a^2,b^2,c^2,d^2,e^2>;
> L := LowIndexSubgroups(G,<4,4>);  
for> if AQInvariants(l) eq [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ] then
for|if> print l, AQInvariants(quo<G|l>);         
for|if> end if;
for> end for;
```

Comment: More generally every involution of a Riemann surface has an even number of fixed points.

Comment: @WillSawin Thanks! Although if $S^2(2,2,2,2,2)$ exists as a  cyclic quotient, the self-homeomorphism on the genus two surface wouldn't correspond to an involution, but rather a symmetry of order 4. Can that be ruled out as well?